# twitter typeahead does not work with my json

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-typeahead

I do have a valid JSON-Feed like this:

```
[[21,"Adlikon"],[131,"Adliswil"]]
```

and I try to set the autocomplete with:

> $('document').ready(function() {
>
> ```
>   $('.city').typeahead({                                
>       name: 'city',
>       remote: 'URL to JSON-Feed'          
>     });
> });
> ```

But this does not work. I guess it's the structure/format of my JSON-Feed, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acoording to Typehead documentation (https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) your JSON data is not well formated.

It should be something like this:

```
// single dataset
$('input.typeahead-devs').typeahead({
  name: 'accounts',
  local: ['timtrueman', 'JakeHarding', 'vskarich']
});
```

Plus in $('document') is as to be $(document).

Comment: Yes, your example works. But I thought, that my JSON could also work - just don't know how...

Comment: I have taken a closer look at the documentation from typehead.js and I think that what you wanted is possible but by using this structure insted:

[{index: 21 value: "Adlikon"},{ index: 131,value: "Adliswil"}]